# How to install RecordMyDesktop in Ubuntu

Tags: software-center

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux. I have installed Ubuntu on Windows using VM Player.

While learning Ubuntu, I want to record the actions I perform on the system. When I searched using chrome browser on Ubuntu, I found the application RecordMyDesktop on apps.ubuntu.com.

When I try to download the file, I am shown a pop-up asking to choose an application to launch the application. I am not sure on how to proceed from now on. I do not see any applications listed in the dialog box. Hence I am a bit confused.

Comment: Anything you find in apps.ubuntu.com you can also find it in Ubuntu Software Center. The "problem" you describe is a matter of Chrome's Browser behavior. Use the Software Center to install any applications you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I understand that you are in the following page,

[image]

Click on the orange color button. You get the following window,

[image]

The above actually wants to open the application `xdg-open`. Click at the bottom right button, for `Launch Application`. You get the following window in Ubuntu Software Center.

[image]

Click on `Install`. The rest of installation proceeds without any problem.

As an alternative, you may want to proceed with the *preferred* command line installation process. Press `Ctrl-Alt-t`, you get a terminal window.

[image]

Type

```
sudo apt-get install recordmydesktop gtk-recordmydesktop
```

Press `Enter`. Provide password if asked for, the installation automatically will proceed from here.

Comment: @VijayBhoomireddy do not forget to click the answer as the correct one.

Comment: @VijayBhoomireddy Glad to be of assistance. I still remember by toddling days when the community extended its hands.

Comment: Any idea how to fix the icon to the top panel?

Comment: @dabad Which icon we are talking about? Would you mind clarifying a bit?

Comment: Sure, sorry for that. I noticed that when running `recordmydesktop` a red -record- button appears in the indicators top panel (where other indicators such as the language, networking, battery, etc.). But as soon as I stop it it disappears. I would like to have it in the top panel all the time, so that I could start it from there.

Comment: @dabad Do not know you can add a launcher to the top indicator panel. But definitely you can add it to the left panel. Either press the Super key (left to the Alt key, and usually has a window/squares icon) and search for `recordmydesktop`, drag the icon to left panel, or start `recordmydesktop`, click right mouse button on the icon which appears in the left panel and select `Lock to Launcher`.